# Keeping *part of* two SVN repositories in sync

Tags: svn

I have some projects and the framework they use in an SVN repository; let's call this repository **A**. Now I want to share the framework with another team on another SVN repository (let's call it **B**), but I would like all changes to the framework that are committed to B to be available on A too.

Of course I can check every now and then what's new on server B, update, copy it to a working copy from server A and commit there. But I would love to keep all history too (should not be a problem as the author of a commit is apparently just a name string), and I'd rather do that automatically when someone commits on server B (in the framework's directory).

Note: in the meanwhile, server A and its projects and its framework's version live their own life. To sum up, it's a bit like branches, but on different repositories, and A to B should be like a merge, but B to A would preferably keep the history of changes too.

Is it possible to do? How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options here:

1. Don't copy/sync the contents of A to B at all. Instead, use [`svn:externals`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.advanced.externals.html) to pull the appropriate items from A into working copies checked out from B. By doing this, you will not be duplicating code from A into B and every time you check out/update your WC from B, you'll have the "latest" from A.
2. Use `svnsync` to selectively sync portions of repository A to repository B. From the [manual](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.reposadmin.maint.html#svn.reposadmin.maint.replication.svnsync-partial):

> As of Subversion 1.5, svnsync also has the ability to mirror a subset of a repository rather than the whole thing. The process of setting up and maintaining such a mirror is exactly the same as when mirroring a whole repository, except that instead of specifying the source repository's root URL when running svnsync init, you specify the URL of some subdirectory within that repository. Synchronization to that mirror will now copy only the bits that changed under that source repository subdirectory. There are some limitations to this support, though. First, you can't mirror multiple disjoint subdirectories of the source repository into a single mirror repository—you'd need to instead mirror some parent directory that is common to both. Second, the filtering logic is entirely path-based, so if the subdirectory you are mirroring was renamed at some point in the past, your mirror would contain only the revisions since the directory appeared at the URL you specified. And likewise, if the source subdirectory is renamed in the future, your synchronization processes will stop mirroring data at the point that the source URL you specified is no longer valid.

Comment: I didn't notice that I can define externals to reference another repository! This is great, but... how would I handle access? Both repositories would have to have the same accounts - or, at least, I should give away an account that members of team B can use to access the shared code on server A...

Comment: Yes, users will need access to both repositories (the accounts don't necessarily have to have the same names or passwords). Do not give one "shared" account for all users to use with the externals. How you manage this is dependent upon how you have your authentication & authorization set up.

Comment: With svnsync, instead, I wouldn't have to let the users of B authenticate on A, am I right?

Comment: With svnsync, your users can be completely isolated - the only "cross-repository" access you'll have to give is for a user account used by svnsync to read A and read/write B.

Comment: Thanks, alroc, just one more question! If I svnsync from B to A, but new revisions were committed to A since the last synchronization, what happens? Does svnsync just "replay" the commits made on B, "sort of like" a merge? Or could problems arise (well, apart from potential merge conflicts)? It seems to me that svnsync is used directly on the repositories, and not on the working copy: how do I manage conflicts?

Comment: @Simone you need to make this a new question.